# set checkbox item to be all checked by default in Oracle APEX

Tags: javascript, css, oracle-apex

i tried to do so by setting item `default value` to be the `list of value` itself but the solution is not perfect.
a button to toggle all items to be checked is a solution i can work with as well

Comment: You need to gibve more detail on what you did, because simply setting the default should work.

Comment: the problem is when i load the page and the default values are set you can see the values but they are not stored in the session. i want them to be stored in the session because i need to execute a PL/SQL insert action with those items as values.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the value to be in session state already when the page is loaded then you can set the item value using a before header process or computation, rather than using the default property.  Use a condition of type "Item is NULL" so that it only sets the item value when it is currently null.